# Importing the values of Properties.Settings.Default in a copy of the application

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I'm creating an auto-update feature for my application. At some point the [application].exe, [application].exe.config, [application].application and [application].exe.manifest files of the latest version are downloaded into a temp folder, the old version starts a run of the new version from the temp folder and then closes itself. The new version then deletes the old version and moves itself out of the temp folder and back to where the old version was.

One issue with this approach is that it doesn't automatically save the `Properties.Settings.Default` values to the new application. As I understand it, these values are stored in `Application.UserAppDataPath`, and this path is the same for both versions. I also use `Properties.Settings.Default.Reload()` when the new version is started, but this doesn't work either.

Are they stored in a different path that is unique for each instance of the program? Or can I in some other way load the values from the old version into the new version?

Answer (score 0):

This question was solved by saving the settings to a text file and reading the values in the new version of the application. If the settings contain objects that are difficult to write in text (which wasn't the case for my application), then you could consider serializing the settings into a custom file.

I still don't understand why the user settings aren't copied to the other version because `Application.UserAppDataPath` is the same for both.